# Increasing height of UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I tried this:

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(164, 282, 461, 60)];
[txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
```

But when I build I cannot see the UITextField, help please. I also tried, field = CGSizeMake but you cannot assign CGSizeMake to a UITextField

Answer (score 3):

you forget to add textfield as subview. Use

```
[self.view addSubView:field];
```

Comment: i already have it placed and connected in the view why do i need to add a subview

Comment: if you want to display any UIview inherited object you need to add it as subview to it's superView which is the main view displayed on screen. You can also do this by using interface builder. If your problem is something else post some more code or send me in mail.

Comment: my subclass is actually uiviewcontroller

Comment: well viewController has a view so the code will work.You are doing something wrong post a screenshot and more code.

Comment: how can i do it (post a screenshot)

Comment: Well i gotta say, this is my ONLY code that includes the uitextfield : 
txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(164, 282, 461, 60)];
    [txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:txt];

I have it IN my view and CONNECTED but when i launch the app, i cant see it

Comment: can you send your app in mail? I'll do it for you.

Comment: well ok i guess whats ur mail

Answer (score 1):

Add it as **subView** in your **main view.** using [`addSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a) method of **UIView**.

Like below.

```
[self.view addSubview:field];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this too

first give constrain to text field as below

[image]

and now simply increase the height of text filed

[image]

and if you don't want constrain then remove it

[image]

i hope it will help you